# What is the forward_to_host in remote port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

https://zaiste.net/ssh_port_forwarding/#remote-port-forwarding

> Remote port forwarding is created with -R parameter.
>
> ```
> ssh -R source_port:forward_to_host:destination_port via_host
> ```
>
> This command connects to via_host. via_host runs a SSH server. It then
>   forwards all connection attempts to source_port on the remote via_host
>   machine to **destination_port port on the local machine (a machine that
>   initiated the ssh command)** . forward_to_host machine must be reachable
>   from the the local machine machine. Forwarding can be also done
>   through Unix sockets.

Is `destination_port` port necessary on the machine that
 initiated the ssh command?

Isn't `destination_port` port  on   machine `forward_to_host` instead?

Isn't `forward_to_host` not necessarily the machine that initiated the ssh command?

Isn't the only requirement on `forward_to_host` is that it must be any machine reachable from the machine that initiated the ssh command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately all the examples in the documentation you link to forward to localhost, and it appears the description of `-R` is restricted to that. You’re correct in thinking that this isn’t an inherent limitation:

- `destination_port` doesn’t have to be on the host where `ssh` is run;
- `destination_port` is indeed on `forward_to_host`;
- `forward_to_host` isn’t necessarily the host where `ssh` is run.

The whole point of `-R` is to allow a remote system to connect to any other system which is reachable from the initiating host. It’s the opposite of `-L`. The target host *can* be the initiating host itself, but it can also be useful to use this for other hosts — *e.g.* when a reverse tunnel is required for confidentiality, or when the initiating system is inside a network which the remote system can’t access directly.

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that `source_port` is only reachable on `localhost` on `via_host`, unless the server has `GatewayPorts` enabled.